# R: any function for Cartesian Product of two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, cartesian

I need to do a cartesian product of two data frames. For example,

```
 A = id weight type
     10    20     a
     10    30     b
     25    10     c
 B = date  report
     2007    y
     2008    n
```

then C would be like after doing cartesian product of A and B

```
 C =  id weight type  date  report
      10    20     a    2007    y
      10    20     a    2008    n
      10    30     b    2007    y
      10    30     b    2008    n
      25    10     c    2007    y
      25    10     c    2008    n
```

as some ids are the same in A, so I cannot use a way like

```
C <- merge(A$id,B$date)
C <- merge(C,A,by="id")
C <- merge(C,B,by="date")
```

This way will generate more rows. Could anyone help me out of here? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`merge(A, B)`, provided there are no columns linking the two, should do this by default, no?

From `?merge` (emphasis mine):

> If by or both by.x and by.y are of length 0 (a length zero vector or NULL), the result, r, is the **Cartesian product** of x and y, i.e., dim(r) = c(nrow(x)*nrow(y), ncol(x) + ncol(y)).

Admittedly, this does require one to know to look in `?merge`. Context-based searching in R is severely lacking; even [rseek](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjS47L81-XOAhWFJpQKHZT6BBoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frseek.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGa2SCQxsN5L-puppc16oSHcWutNQ) doesn't immediately provide this.

Comment: you are right. thanks a lot!!